# How to save the image on the photo album after perform the 3D Transform?

Tags: iphone

How to save the 3D transformed image on the photo album? I am using `CATransform3DRotate` for change the transform. I am not able to save the image. Image saving code.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Is it possible to save the 3D Transformed image? Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this link http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/05/save-image-in-library-with-only-in-one.html

Comment: Please see this link this my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421850/how-merge-the-perspective-of-the-image-on-the-background-image-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(UIImage *) glToUIImage {
    NSInteger myDataLength = 320 * 480 * 4;

    // allocate array and read pixels into it.
    GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, 320, 480, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    // gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
    // there's gotta be a better way, but this works.
    GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
    for(int y = 0; y < 480; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 320 * 4; x++)
        {
            buffer2[(479 - y) * 320 * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * 320 + x];
        }
    }

    // make data provider with data.
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);

    // prep the ingredients
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * 320;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    // make the cgimage
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(320, 480, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    // then make the uiimage from that
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    return myImage;
}

-(void)captureToPhotoAlbum {
    UIImage *image = [self glToUIImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil);
}
```

also see full tutorial for save openGL Image in photoAlbum from [this link](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1861)

and also see my blog with this post.. [captureimagescreenshot-of-view](http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/06/captureimagescreenshot-of-view.html)

**2 .** also use `ALAssetsLibrary` to save image

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
    if (error) {
    // TODO: error handling
    } else {
    // TODO: success handling
    }
}];
[library release];
```

Comment: Thanks Paras Joshi. This code only supported for the 2D transform not supported in 3D transformed images.

Comment: @Mani , see my edited answer.. may be you get some idea or solve your problem.. i hope so.. :)

Comment: Thank you. I am not using OPenGL. I will try this. Do you have any idea using coregraphics to solve this problem.

Comment: i think you can get image with this code bcoz you use 3d and here also get every core-graphics context with imageRef so try with this code and also change some code with your requirement .. ]

Comment: Thank you Paras Joshi. I will try.

Comment: hey @Mani also try second option from answer.. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19219/discussion-between-mani-and-paras-joshi)

Comment: Thank you...Can you explain about ALAssetsLibrary.,

Comment: see this link @Mani http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/08/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);
```

You only need completionTarget, completionSelector and contextInfo if you want to be notified when the image is done saving, otherwise you can pass in nil.

ok then try like this..

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(YOUR_VIEW.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

It will capture your view as like screenshot and save to photo album

- YOUR_VIEW = paas your edited image's superview..

Comment: Image saving perfectly. My problem is 3D transformed image. Please see rhis link This is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421850/how-merge-the-perspective-of-the-image-on-the-background-image-view

Comment: Thanks Irshad Mansuri. Already try this, but not working for 3D transform. Any other idea. Please help me.